# Sum data with partial string match

Tags: google-sheets, google-visualization

I'm trying to sum the data in columns where the first column in each row contains a partial match to a keyword.

I've used wildcards but never in a filter or sum, and they don't seem to be working in this setting. What's wrong?

---

**Using FILTER()**

```
=SUM(FILTER(
'_!query-AllData'!B2:B,
'_!query-AllData'!A2:A="*willow*"))
```

> No matches are found in FILTER evaluation.

**Using REGEXMATCH()**

```
=SUM(FILTER(
'_!query-AllData'!B2:B,
REGEXMATCH('_!query-AllData'!A2:A,"*willow*")))
```

> No matches are found in FILTER evaluation.

**Using QUERY()** [in this case, A31 = willow]

```
=SUM(QUERY(
'_!query-AllData'!A2:B,
"SELECT B WHERE A LIKE '"&A31&"'"))
```

> Query completed with an empty output.

---

Sample data:

```
 A                              | B
--------------------------------|---
 /willow/                       | 2
 /willow/                       | 1
 /willow/?CID=EM_iOS_page-share | 3
 /willow/?skipSplash=true       | 1
 /willow/?fromReader=true       | 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=sumproduct(regexmatch(A2:A, "willow"), B2:B)
```

or

```
=sum(filter(B2:B, regexmatch(A2:A, "willow")))
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up going the route of `=SUMIFS(B2:B,A2:A,"*"&"willow"&"*")`. Either of the above also work.